# How to Solve a Function Given Some of its Solutions

Tags: sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics

Suppose you have a function that defines a series. And suppose you know Some (not all) of the elements of that series. 
For example, you know your function is n/J, where n is for all positive integers and J is a constant. Your choice for the value of J determines the elements of the resulting series. You also know some of the elements you want to find in that series. 
How would you find the value of J, given its functions and some of its solutions?

Comment: You cannot find J, in general, if you know some values of the sequence but not their indices.

Comment: Unfortunate. Supposing you knew their indices, do you know of a general procedure to find J?

Comment: Of course. If you know, for instance, that $a_{10}=7$, then $10/J=7$ and $J=10/7$.

Comment: Ohh, of course. Thank You!